# What is the difference between global and :: in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I am working with an EDA SW. It requires me to rely on global variables.
Say I have a proc, and I am looking for a global variable CCK_FOO. I have 2 choices:

1. Use `global CCK_FOO` within the code.
2. Use `::CCK_FOO`

In terms of "management level", these appear identical. Is there an "under the hood" pro and con for either of the methods? I actually prefer using `::`, as it minimizes the chances of accidental override.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the hood, using `::CCK_FOO` goes through the parsed variable name route every time the execution engine uses it, whereas `global CCK_FOO` allows the engine to set up a local variable (with a local variable table — LVT — slot) that is linked to the global variable. Accesses via the LVT is much faster because that's just an index into a C array (and an extra pointer dereference because it's a link) whereas looking up a global variable means doing a hash table lookup (there's a hash table for variables in the global namespace implementation). The actual internal parse of `::CCK_FOO` into `::` and `CCK_FOO` is cached.

In practical terms, it's perhaps *slightly* faster to use `::CCK_FOO` if you are only accessing a variable once, but as soon as you use it twice (let alone more) you get better performance by paying the extra cost of `global CCK_FOO` and accessing it via LVT indexing.

```
% proc style1 {} {
    set ::CCK_FOO abc
}
% proc style2 {} {
    global CCK_FOO
    set CCK_FOO abc
}
% time { style1 } 100000
0.52350635 microseconds per iteration
% time { style2 } 100000
0.5267007100000001 microseconds per iteration
```

Note, times between code above and code below are not comparable as they do different amounts of other work. Look instead at the differences in timings between `style1` and `style2`.

```
% proc style1 {} {
    set ::CCK_FOO [string reverse $::CCK_FOO]
}
% proc style2 {} {
    global CCK_FOO
    set CCK_FOO [string reverse $CCK_FOO]
}
% time { style1 } 100000
0.9733970200000001 microseconds per iteration
% time { style2 } 100000
0.78782093 microseconds per iteration
# Calibration...
% time { string reverse abc } 100000
0.28694849 microseconds per iteration
```

As you can see, *with just two accesses,* we're getting quite a lot of speedup by using `global`.

Comment: All timings are on my machine using Tcl 8.6.3; you will have different measurements. Mileage may vary. Not valid where void. The state of California would like you to know that medical research causes cancer in rats.