# Fastest way to access namespace variables in TCL

Tags: namespaces, tcl, lookup

I have SW in TCL.
I need to set and/or query variables in a different namespace.
Should I use (for exampele):

```
global ::namespace1::varname1
set ::namespace1::varname1 $val
##more code to access/write into a variable
```

Or should I use procedures to achieve the same, for example?

```
namespace1::setVarname1 $val
namespace1::getVarname1
```

Which lookup is faster? The 2nd method is definitely safer.
We are using TCL 8.5, and will upgrade in the future to Tcl 8.6
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37296301/974155

Comment: Similar question, but not the same. 1 is calling a proc which uses a variable, not global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a procedure, the fastest way is to use `global`, `variable`, `upvar` or `namespace upvar` to map the namespace variable as a local variable. Or at least it is fastest if you're accessing (reading or writing) the variable more than once; the exact choice of which of the above commands to use depends on what you're doing, and in some cases can make quite a bit of difference to the speed, but for constant variable names it doesn't matter too much. The same also applies to lambda terms or class methods; it's the same underlying mechanism.

Outside a procedure, if you're not already executing in the namespace where the variable is from, the fastest way of access is probably to use the fully-qualified name. (Tcl will cache the parse of the name in the internal representation of the name, which will speed things up quite a bit.) On the other hand, if it is a variable in the current namespace then using the unqualified name might be slightly faster. Provided you declared the variable with the `variable` command (for namespaces other than `::`) to prevent any troubles with the variable resolver.

Overall, rather than just asking here you can find out for yourself. The `time` command makes testing very easy:

```
% info patch
8.5.9
% set x 1
1
% time {incr x} 10000
0.3075357 microseconds per iteration
% time {incr ::x} 10000
0.3728569 microseconds per iteration
```

You should check with *your* code; don't assume that my timings and yours are the same.